# PHP MVC LARAVEL

Tags: php, pdo

how can I show a array in the view?

Controller:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('links', 'links.UserId', '=', 'users.UserId')
    ->select('users.*', 'links.*')
    ->get();

return view('site.user', ['UserId' => $users]);
```

I want to do foreach in LINKS, but not in users...

VIEW (users) (WITHOUT foreach):

```
<h1><?=$user->UserName . ' ' . $user->UserLastName?></h1>
```

LINKS (foreach):

```
<li class="white-balloon">
    <?=$user->LinkName?>
</li>
```

Comment: You code doesn't follow the Laravel way to do. You should use relationships. Also your column names doesn't follow the Laravel pattern. Slow down and read the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/).

Comment: @EliasSoares at least refer to the right documentation.... [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) see the part of `One To One` and `One To Many`. The advantage of defining your tables and models the 'right' way is that you yourself don't have to worry about joined queries and optimisation.

Comment: @Jeffrey, looks like he have a lot to read, that's why I referenced the doc home. :-)

Comment: EliasSoares true :) @halysson-teves-dos-santos [Laracast](http://laracasts.com) for in case you don't like reading!

Answer (score 0):

First

```
return view('site.user', ['UserId' => $users]);
```

should be

```
return view('site.user', ['users' => $users]);
```

unless you want to use the variable UserId.
To loop over a variable in blade, use:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>This is a link {{ $user->LinkName }}</p>
@endforeach
```

or in PHP

```
<?PHP foreach( $users AS $user)
{
    echo $user->LinkName;
} ?>
```

Note: if you have multiple links per user, you should redefine your SQL query. This method gives allot of overhead.

Here a good [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14) about Laravel relationships